# How long does Facebook cache opengraph page preview images for?

Tags: facebook

I've manually changed the home page Facebook open graph preview image, but when I paste the home page URL in Facebook, it still uses an old image.

How long before Facebook updates its cache / uses the updated open graph preview image?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook automatically clears the cache every 24 hours: Actually Facebook scrapes the pages and updates the cache every 24 hours.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs

The above is the link where you can see this.

Comment: We're facing the problem that Facebook is still using the original image we used around 14 days ago.

Comment: Where on that page is the mention of the cache?

Comment: Yes. You can set it to scrape more often..

Comment: If you want to know your scrape information then
1. Visit the FB page https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/
2. Enter your domain.
3. Click the button "Fetch new scrape information"
4. Done

Comment: I don't think we should have to do this every time we set a new FB image in Yoast SEO :-)